# Controlling Infinite Sequence Display In "lein repl"

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'd like to improve some features of `lein repl` to match features that are in the `cider repl`. Specifically in cider, results get elided (triple dot truncation) when

- I evaluate an infinite sequence or
- I print out an infinite sequence

In `lein repl`, the printing bit can be handled by the [*print-length*](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*print-length*) var. But I'm trying to get the same result for just evaluating an infinite sequence. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-85.html) explains some of the options, in particular there is also `(set! *print-level* 15)` for recursive structures as well as `repl-utils/add-break-thread!`, which allows you to CTRL-C out of a runaway evalutation without killing the JVM process and forcing you to start all over.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful post. But still no dice. Neither `(set! *print-length* 103)` nor `(set! *print-level* 15)` help with this ***lein repl***. `(iterate inc 0)` still hangs there.